# Обход блокировки при парсинге

Tags: node.js, парсер, selenium, puppeteer, веб-скрейпинг

У меня есть довольно простой код на puppeteer:

```
const BookAppointment = async () => { 
  puppeteer.use(pluginStealth())      

  const proxy = await getProxy()

  const {cookies, userAgent} = await setupProxy(proxy)  
      
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({     
      slowMo: 10, 
      headless: false, 
      args: [  
          `--start-maximized`, 
          `--proxy-server=${proxy}`,   
      ], 
  })  
  const page = await browser.newPage();  

  await page.setCookie(...cookies)   

  await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    "User-Agent": userAgent, 
  })  

  await page.goto(`https://icp.administracionelectronica.gob.es/icpplus/index.html`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })

  await page.waitForSelector("#form")    
  await page.waitForTimeout(2200) 
  await page.select("#form", "/icpplus/citar?p=2&locale=es")  
  await page.waitForTimeout(2200)  
  await Promise.all([page.click("#btnAceptar"), page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil:'networkidle2'})])

  await page.waitForSelector("#sede")
  await page.waitForTimeout(2200) 
  await Promise.all([page.select("#sede", "2"), page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil:'networkidle2'})])

  await page.waitForSelector(".mf-input__l")
  await page.waitForSelector("#btnAceptar")
  await page.select(".mf-input__l", "4112")
  await page.waitForTimeout(2200)
  await Promise.all([page.click("#btnAceptar"), page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil:'networkidle2'})])

  await page.waitForSelector("#btnEntrar")
  await page.waitForTimeout(2200)  
  await page.click("#btnEntrar")
  await page.waitForSelector("#txtIdCitado")
  await page.waitForSelector("#txtDesCitado")
  await page.waitForSelector("#btnEnviar")
  await page.type("#txtIdCitado", "Z0563935A") 
  await page.waitForTimeout(2200) 
  await page.type("#txtDesCitado", "KATERINA SOLODA" )
  await page.waitForTimeout(2200)
  await Promise.all([page.click("#btnEnviar"), page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil:'networkidle2'})])

  await page.waitForSelector("#btnEnviar")
  await page.waitForTimeout(2200) 

  await Promise.all([page.click("#btnEnviar"), page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil:'networkidle2'})])

  await page.waitForSelector("#txtTelefonoCitado")
  await page.waitForTimeout(2200)  
  await page.type("#txtTelefonoCitado", "653615024")
  await page.type("#emailUNO", "lina.keratina@gmail.com")
  await page.type("#emailDOS", "lina.keratina@gmail.com") 
  await page.waitForTimeout(2200)  
  await Promise.all([page.click("#btnSiguiente"), page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil:'domcontentloaded'})])  

  await page.waitForSelector("#btnSiguiente")
  await page.waitForSelector("#cita1")
  

  try {
    const element = await page.waitForSelector(".img-thumbnail", {timeout: 5000}) 
    await page.waitForTimeout(randomTimeout()) 
    await element.screenshot({ 
      path: `post_image_1.jpg`  
    })
    const key = await solveCaptcha(`post_image_1.jpg`)
    await page.type("#captcha", key)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  await page.click("#cita1")
  await page.click("#btnSiguiente")
  await page.waitForTimeout(2000)
  await page.waitForSelector(".btn")
  await page.click(".btn")
  await page.waitForTimeout(10000)
  await Promise.all([page.goto("https://icp.administracionelectronica.gob.es/icpplus/index.html"), page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil:'domcontentloaded'})]) 
  
  
  const pageCookies = await page.cookies()  

  writeProxyCookies(pageCookies, proxy)
}
```

Эта функция запускается множество раз, при этом сохраняя куки страницы на локалку.
Иногда сервер вообще не блокирует запросы, но чаще всего он кидает вот такое:

```
The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrador.

Your support ID is: < 2580972395890823306>

[Go Back]
```

после двух-трех запросов.
Сервер дропает запросы в простом браузере только в том случае, если удалить все куки, и сделать несколько запросов(и даже так количество запросов после удаления кук может варьироваться от 1 до 20).
Сервер использует JSESSIONID для идентификации пользователя.
Но как только я пробую зайти на сайт из под puppeteer, сразу начинается жуть.
Я сравнивал хедеры запроса из простого хрома и puppeteer, отличаются только 2 хедера: Pragma и Cache-Control. В простом браузере они установлены в no-cache, а в puppeteer Cache-Control: max-age=0, а Pragma вообще нет..
Если я добавляю эти хедеры в puppeteer, то сервер моментально дропает все запросы.

Я так же пытался избежать паттернизации трафика, путем отправления рандомных запросов между этапами парсинга, но это ничего не меняет. Есть подозрение, что сервер использует какой-то WAF.

Я бы хотел получить какие-то рекомендации, советы или ресурсы, на которых есть информации про обходы подобных систем безопасности, ибо прошерстил кучу статей, и везде пишут только про сохранение кук между сессиями, изменение хедеров запросов, использование прокси и избежание паттернизации.

Весь код находится в репо: https://github.com/pauf419/SedeAutomateTest
Сервер пропускает трафик только из Дании, Франции, Чехии, Испании и Эстонии.

Заранее спасибо за предоставленную помощь

Comment: Существует еще защита на транспортном уровне называемая `TLS`, для её обхода юзал [cycleTLS](https://github.com/Danny-Dasilva/CycleTLS) на `Golang`. Это чисто предположение о возможной защите

Comment: @MoloF Странно то, что если я из puppeteer браузера делаю все действия не через апи, а просто руками ввожу данные, то все... работает без блокировки! Совершенно не понятен принцип работы этого детектора... Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Я уже искал элементы-ловушки, но ничего не нашел.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `slowMo` и посмотрите на каком этапе ломается ваш скрипт

Comment: @MoloF Уже проставлял разные slowMo, и добавлял рандомные таймауты между действиями. Совершенно никак не сказывается на положение